# Spring dynamic form

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I getting a error when I try to build a form this way:

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private int age;

public Person() {
}

public Person(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController {

@GetMapping
public ModelAndView add() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("Neon", 4));
    mav.addObject("persons", persons);
    return mav;
}
```

}

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
        <div th:each="person,status : ${persons}" class="form-group" >
            <label>Name</label><input th:field="${persons[__${status.index}__].name}" th:value="${person.name}" />
            <label>Age</label><input th:field="${persons[__${status.index}__].age}" th:value="${person.age}" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Error:

Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'persons[0]' available as request attribute.

I want to build a form that has dynamic fields

Someone can help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `th:field="${persons[__${status.index}__].name}"`?

Comment: I think that `th:field="${persons[__${status.index}__].name}"` should bind with the attribute name of Person class.

Comment: And in the submit I expected that the field's value will be set in the attribute name

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you can't use a `List` as the object that will be POSTed.  It should work if you build another java object (in my example,  with a getter/setter for `List<Person> persons;`)

(example) Person form

```
public class PersonForm {
    private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${personForm}">
    <div th:each="person,status : ${personForm.persons}" class="form-group" >
        <label>Name</label><input th:field="*{persons[__${status.index}__].name}" />
        <label>Age</label><input th:field="*{persons[__${status.index}__].age}" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```